# Nested Forms and Building associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I'm working on a add to cart form. It looks something like this

```
#Models
Order.rb
  has_many :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items, :allow_destroy => true

LineItem.rb
  has_one :product
  belongs_to :order

Product.rb
  belongs_to :line_item
```

I'd like to create a form in product#show to allow multiple related products to be added to the order/cart at once, basically *create or update a line item for each product*.

Probably something like this in the view (HAML to keep it brief).

```
-form_for @order do |f|
 - if has_related?
   - for related in @products.related_products
     - f.field_for :line_item do |li_form|
       = li_form.text_field :quantity
       = li_form.hidden_field :product_id
       = related.product_name
```

What would it take to actually make something like this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need more info to be sure, but it seems that a LineItem `belongs_to :product` and Product should NOT `belong_to :line_item` unless there really is a 1-1 relationship there (which wouldn't make sense to me, and doesn't follow the normal convention of these sorts of systems)

Note** using `-` before `form_for` and `fields_for` has been deprecated in ***rails 3*** in favor of `=` since the form does actually render html

`= fields_for :line_items do |li_form|` is the syntax for a has_many relationship

The rest all depends on your user experience design.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, my models are a little more complex but I tried to simplify for the question. LineItem actually does belong_to Product and Product has_many :line_items. I'm working with Rails 2.3.10. Any thoughts on how to create a new line_item association for each product in @product.related_products?

Comment: In your controller, set related and then build the line items: `related.each{|r| @order.line_items.build(:quantity => 0, :product_id => r.id)`